# Class vs. entity in OWL

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, protege

In Protégé, I want to express in OWL the following sentence:

> Every person is happy if all his children are successful.

For that reason, I created a class `Person`, which has a subclass `Child`.

Now, in the same logic, I would create a class `Status` and create a subclass `Successful`. However, another student said that `Successful` should be an *entity* (a concept that is?).

What should `Successful` be, an *entity* or a *class*?

Comment: Successful has exact two status: true or false. So, it is not a class.

Comment: But what it is @AMartinNo1? Maybe you can post an answer please.

Comment: If it is tomorrow unanswered I am going to write an answer - I have not much time atm. For now I would create a global attribute and a worker. The worker decides wether the child is successful.

Comment: I have no idea what a worker is. It was not covered. OK @AMartinNo1.

Comment: In OWL, named classes, properties, named datatypes and naned individuals are all called entities, so technically your Successful class is already an entity. As @matentzn suggests, I think your colleague meant individual.

Comment: I see @Ignazio, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We typically refer to entities as an all encompassing concept for classes, individuals and properties. Concept and class are simply synonyms. I assume your classmate meant to say "individual". I personally avoid individuals when writing concept expressions, but in this case, it does not matter whether you use a class or an individual. You need to define a class like HappyPerson = Person and hasChild some (Person and hasStatus some Happy) and hasChild only (Person and hasStatus some Happy). You don't technically need the Child class at all. For a detailed introduction on how to model people and there relationships, see: http://owl.cs.manchester.ac.uk/publications/talks-and-tutorials/fhkbtutorial/